# Trouble activating Single Sign-On (SSO) on Trial subscription to Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle, cloud, single-sign-on

everybody

First, I am not sure I am really on topic here, but Oracle's own "cloud" support and community forums are not helpful (they get very little traffic and there were no responses yet). Maybe somebody over here has experience with Oracle's cloud offerings and has broader understanding than I have?

We're in the process of evaluating the Oracle's IaaS offerings, and I've subscribed to a Trial access to cloud services (it includes all the current cloud offerings like compute, storage, backup, Dbaas etc).

Trying to install the apps from the Oracle Cloud Marketplace, I discovered that enabling SSO is a prerequisite, and turning it on is described as follows:

> You must authorize your Oracle single sign-on account to access your
>   identify domain, to enable discovery of all services:
>
> - From the My Services dashboard, under Quick Links, select Set Preferences.
> - Under Set Preferences, tick (select) the Permission Settings checkbox."

When I show the preferences, the only ones I see are for Languages and Notifications but nothing for "Permission Settings":

[preferences screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1i9u.png)
Does it mean trial subscriptions don't have access to this functionality (namely enabling SSO) or maybe I am missing something?

Regards

Edit: I had a response from the oracle's "chat" support:

> Please note that this functionality is available in Trial accounts but in some of the Compute Zones it is not enabled yet. I believe your trial Compute Zone falls in that. Development team is enabling this on a phased manner and we hope to see this enabled in your Compute Zone soon though we do not have any timelines shared with us at the moment.

This means for me the functionality isn't yet available and there is no dates of its availability announced.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is spot-on. Unfortunately, I am running into the same exact problem and haven't found a workaround or explanation. Not sure if this is a limitation of the trial subscription or if Oracle hasn't updated their documentation. If this is a limitation of the trial subscription, then it is a terrible setback for those of us who want to evaluate and document the different service offerings. Hoping someone can chime in soon on this. Thanks for posting this as I now know that I'm not the only one out there experiencing this problem! Best Regards,
Jeff

Comment: hello, Jeff, I had the following explanation from the Oracle's "chat" support: "Please note that this functionality is available in Trial accounts but in some of the Compute Zones it is not enabled yet. I believe your trial Compute Zone falls in that. Development team is enabling this on a phased manner and we hope to see this enabled in your Compute Zone soon though we do not have any timelines shared with us at the moment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a response from the oracle's "chat" support:

> Please note that this functionality is available in Trial accounts but in some of the Compute Zones it is not enabled yet. I believe your trial Compute Zone falls in that. Development team is enabling this on a phased manner and we hope to see this enabled in your Compute Zone soon though we do not have any timelines shared with us at the moment.

This means for me the functionality isn't yet available and there is no dates of its availability announced. I guess this closes my question, the answer is "not available for trial accounts as of yet".

Comment: Just a follow up: trial accounts in EMEA data centers are still not configurable with sso as of today.